# Reordering factor for plotting using forcats and ggplot2 packages from tidyverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

First of all, thanks<sup>^13</sup> to [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/). I want the bars in the chart below to follow the same factor levels reordered by `forcats::fct_reorder ()`. Surprisingly, I see different order of levels in the data set when `View ()`ed as when they are displayed in the chart (see below). The chart should illustrate the number of failed students before and after the bonus marks (I want to sort the bars based on the number of failed students before the bonus).

**MWE**

```
  ggplot (df) +
  geom_bar (aes (forcats::fct_reorder (subject, FailNo, .desc= TRUE), FailNo, fill = forcats::fct_rev (Bonus)), position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
  theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1.5, hjust=1.5, size = rel (1.2)))
```

**Data output of dput (df)**

```
structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L,
4L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 10L,
8L, 12L, 11L), .Label = c("CAB_1", "DEM_1", "SSR_2", "RRG_1",
"TTP_1", "TTP_2", "IMM_1", "RRG_2", "DEM_2", "VRR_2", "PRS_2",
"COM_2", "MEB_2", "PHH_1", "PHH_2"), class = "factor"), Bonus = structure(c(2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("After", "Before"), class = "factor"),
    FailNo = c(29, 28, 20, 18, 15, 13, 12, 8, 5, 4, 4, 2, 21,
    16, 16, 14, 7, 10, 10, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1)), .Names = c("subject",
"Bonus", "FailNo"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-24L))
```

[image]

**Bar chart**
[image]

**The issue**

According to the table above, `SSR_2` var should come in the fifth rank and `IMM_1` in the sixth, however in the chart we see these two variables *swapping* their positions. How to sort it right after tidyverse in this case?

Comment: Use `factor` with `unique` levels for your x -axis. 
`ggplot (df) +
  geom_bar (aes (factor(forcats::fct_reorder (subject, FailNo, .desc= TRUE),levels=unique(forcats::fct_reorder (subject, FailNo, .desc= TRUE))), FailNo, fill = forcats::fct_rev (Bonus)), position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +  theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1.5, hjust=1.5, size = rel (1.2)))`

Comment: @SRivero feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `factor` with `unique` levels for your x -axis.

```
ggplot (df) + 
 geom_bar (aes(factor(forcats::fct_reorder
 (subject, FailNo, .desc= TRUE), 
 levels=unique(subject)), 
 FailNo, 
 fill = forcats::fct_rev (Bonus)), 
 position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') + 
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1.5, hjust=1.5, size = rel (1.2)))
```

Edited: @dotorate comment

Comment: `levels=unique(forcats::fct_reorder (subject, FailNo, .desc= TRUE))` can be shortened to `levels=unique(subject)` and works too.

Answer (score 0):

Sort failNo before the bonus

```
library(dplyr)
df_before_bonus <- df %>% filter(Bonus == "Before") %>% arrange(desc(FailNo))
```

Use FailNo before the bonus to create the factor

```
df$subject <- factor(df$subject, levels = df_before_bonus$subject, ordered = TRUE)
```

Updated plot

```
ggplot(df) +
    geom_bar(aes (x = subject, y = FailNo, fill = as.factor(Bonus)), 
             position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
    theme (axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1.5, hjust=1.5, size = rel (1.2)))
```

[image]